# package not being permanently installed inside the python virtual environment

Tags: python

I'm building a rest-api using the Django Python framework. I'm using many external python packages. I have created a python virtual environment (`python -m venv venv`) and after activating the `venv` environment (`venv\Scripts\activate`), I installed the `requests` package (`python -m pip install requests`). Then I pushed my project to my git repo and cloned it onto another machine. When I tried to run my Django project, it asked me to install the `requests` package again. Why or how can I permanently install packages into my python virtual environment or someplace else where I wouldn't have to install packages again on different machines? I'm looking for a solution similar to `NodeJS - npm` of installing packages as all the packages are locally installed into the `node_modules` folder of the project and you don't have to reinstall them on different machines. Thanks

Comment: Is your `venv/` directory versioned?

Comment: I haven't specifically set anything related to version. But I created the `venv` in Python 3.10.7

Comment: They were asking if you have it under version control as part of your Git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment itself is not shareable in the way you specify. I'd recommend to use Docker for this use-case. If you create a docker image which has the correct dependencies, then you can easily operate in the same environment on different computers. The python venv cannot be used this way.

Nevertheless, if your `requirements.txt` files specify package versions, then the `venv` you create on the two machines should be relatively similar (depending of course on other parameters like the OS, python version, etc.).